# modify Finatra response header

Tags: finatra

Finatra returns framework's name by default in response header as "Server" -> Finatra,

for some reason, I don't want to expose this part of information.

Is there anyway to modify it? I have tried filters and response.ok.header.set. but no luck.

thanks all.

Server header information:

[image: server header information]

Answer (score 0):

Finatra sets `Server` header in `com.twitter.finatra.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter`. You may use [HttpResponseFilter](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/blob/57555f8015876d8acc10b5d04b4070b39d51d395/http/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finatra/http/filters/HttpResponseFilter.scala#L49) directly or via [CommonFilters](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/blob/57555f8015876d8acc10b5d04b4070b39d51d395/http/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finatra/http/filters/CommonFilters.scala).

If you want to override this behavior, I suggest defining a new `Filter` like this

```
@Singleton
class CustomServerNameFilter extends SimpleFilter[Request, Response] {
  def apply(request: Request, service: Service[Request, Response]): Future[Response] =
    service(request).map { response =>
      response.headerMap.set(HttpHeaders.Server, "My Custom Server")
      response
    }
}
```

And using it before [HttpResponseFilter](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/blob/57555f8015876d8acc10b5d04b4070b39d51d395/http/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finatra/http/filters/HttpResponseFilter.scala#L49) or [CommonFilters](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/blob/57555f8015876d8acc10b5d04b4070b39d51d395/http/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finatra/http/filters/CommonFilters.scala) like

```
class MyFinatraServer extends HttpServer {

  override protected def configureHttp(router: HttpRouter): Unit =
    router
      .filter[CustomServerNameFilter]
      .filter[CommonFilters]
      .add[MyController]

}
```